# NullPointerException, can't understand why

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make this java exercise, but i receive a NullPointerException and i can't understand why

```
public class CV 
{
    private String nome;
    private HashSet<Pubblicazione> pubblicazioni;

    public CV(String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void aggiungiPubblicazione(Pubblicazione pub)
    {
        pubblicazioni.add(pub);(*)
    }

    public String getNome(){return nome;}
    public HashSet<Pubblicazione> getPubblicazioni(){ return pubblicazioni; }
}



public class ProfEvaluator
{
    private CV curriculum;
    public ProfEvaluator(CV curriculum){ this.curriculum = curriculum; }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CV cv = new CV("Mario Rossi");
        cv.aggiungiPubblicazione(new Pubblicazione("pub1",10, "Mario Rossi",   "Luigi Bianchi", "Giuseppe Verdi")); (*)
        cv.aggiungiPubblicazione(new Pubblicazione("pub2",10, "Mario Rossi", "Giuseppe Verdi"));
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CV.aggiungiPubblicazione(CV.java:18)
    at ProfEvaluator.main(ProfEvaluator.java:53)
```

I've made a debug with eclipse and there are no NullPointers.
The exception is thrown in the line marked with (*) (the lines indicated by the error messages are wrong 'cause i've pasted only the parts of the program that i considered involved with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `pubblicazioni` before using it:

```
public CV(String nome)
{
    this.nome = nome;
    this.pubblicazioni = new HashSet<Pubblicazione>();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You **do have** a null pointer. You try to access `pubblicazioni` before instantiating it.

You can add to the constructor:

```
public CV(String nome)
{
    this.nome = nome;
    this.pubblicazioni = new HashSet<>();
}
```

As @ZouZou stated:

If you're not dealing with Java 7, replace `= new HashSet<>();` with `= new HashSet<Pubblicazione>();`

Comment: If you're not dealing with Java 7, replace `= new HashSet<>();` by = `new HashSet<Pubblicazione>();`

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your HashSet `pubblicazioni` before adding values to it.